# Strongloop Studio not working well

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I'm having some trouble with Studio Beta. It's not retrieving my models correctly and I'm getting this error from my browser console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://example.com:45406/scripts/modules/model/model.services.js:181:36)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.forEach (http://example.com:45406/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:303:11)
    at http://example.com:45406/scripts/modules/model/model.services.js:163:23
    at http://example.com:45406/scripts/vendor/angular/angular-resource.js:554:32
    at wrappedCallback (http://example.com:45406/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:10930:81)
    at http://example.com:45406/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:11016:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://example.com:45406/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:11936:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://example.com:45406/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:11762:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://example.com:45406/scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js:12042:24)
```

Note that I replaced my actual URL with example.com

Answer (score 0):

We have released a new version of the beta that should fix this issue. Please re run

npm install -g http://get-studio.strongloop.com/strong-studio.tgz

to upgrade.